# I am trying to execute a file in sh with nodejs but the console tells me that the file cannot be found

Tags: javascript, node.js, sh

This is the code that i found on the internet:

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
var yourscript = exec('sh launch.sh', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
   console.log(stdout);
   console.log(stderr);
   if (error !== null) {
     console.log(`exec error: ${error}`);
   }
});
```

and here is my sh file which is in the same file as my previous code:

```
   echo "Hi There!"
```

but each time I run the program the console shows me:

```
   exec error: Error: Command failed: sh launch.sh
   sh: 0: Can't open launch.sh
```

Can somebody help me with my code please?

Answer (score 2):

First, you seem to have a file permissions issue, so to fix that, start by setting the file permissions for the user as the user needs execution permissions:

```
chmod 755 launch.sh
```

Second, the code you found online is using "exec" that is now deprecated in favour of builtin child_process.execFile. So, for your needs the code would look a bit like:

```
var child_process = require('child_process');

child_process.exec('sh launch.sh', function(error, stdout, stderr){
    console.log(stdout);
});
```

This should help to get started! The inner command `sh launch.sh` should be executable in the command line, directly, so tested without running the main host or nodejs script! Type the command in your CLI and press enter! Alternatively to calling `sh launch.sh` do `/bin/sh launch.sh`

Of course, you might want to look at docs to improve the implementation and fully understand file `permissions` under your OS, what `sh` means and finally child_process.exec.

https://www.linux.com/tutorials/understanding-linux-file-permissions

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html